# What was Moses' staff made of?

Tags: animals, moshe-rabbeinu, miracle, parashas-shemos, chukas

What was Moses' staff made of? Copper? What's relationship between Moses' staff being turned into a snake in Parsha Sh'mot and the incident in Parsha Chuckat if there is any?

Answer (score 6):

It was made out of Sapphire and had the words דצ"ך עד"ש באח"ב  , (an acronym of the Ten Plagues) inscribed on it. See Pirkei Avos chapter 5:6 with its commentaries.There are also midrashim on this topic.

From Pirkei D'Reb Eliezer 40

> ר' לוי אומ' אותו המטה שנברא בין השמשות נמסר לאדם הראשון מגן עדן ואדם מסרו לחנוך וחנוך מסרו לנח ונח לשם ושם מסרו לאברהם ואברהם ליצחק ויצחק ליעקב ויעקב הוריד אותו למצרים ומסרו ליוסף בנו כשמת יוסף ושללו ביתו נתנה בפלטרין של פרעה והיה יתרו אחד מחרטומי מצרים וראה את המטה ואת האותות אשר עליו וחמד אותו בלבו ולקחו והביאו ונטעו בתוך הגן של ביתו ולא היה אדם יכול לקרב אליו עוד כשבא משה לתוך ביתו נכנס לגן ביתו של יתרו וראה את המטה וקרא את האותות אשר עליו ושלף ידו ולקחו וראה יתרו למשה ואמר זה עתיד לגאול את ישראל ממצרים...... .

This is the history of the staff: In short, Moshe was the only one who could pull the staff from it's place which showed he will be the redeemer of Israel. Also it was created Ben Hashmashos  on the 6th day of creation and was given to Adam who passed it down until Moshe came upon it.

Comment: hmmmm http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excalibur When does your Midrash date from?

Comment: @DoubleAA According to Wikipedia, the later parts of [Pirke De-Rabbi Eliezer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pirke_De-Rabbi_Eliezer) date to the 9th century. Doesn't Excalibur date to the 12th century?

Comment: @Doubleaa ,just goes to show you alot of things come from the Torah

Comment: @sam Or that [modern rabbis](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29352/759) aren't the first to take analogies from the world around them.

Comment: @DoubleAA [this](https://www.nli.org.il/he/books/NNL_ALEPH002256025/NLI) might interest you...