# Quote from Chazal

Tags: sources-mekorot, quotations, chazal

I read in [*Real Power*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0978631358) on page 47, the following:

*“If you are not going upward then you are automatically falling downward.”*
—Chazal

Does anyone know if this is a *Gemara* or *Medrash* etc.?

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29352/603

Answer (score 5):

One place this is mentioned is the Chafetz Chaim's *Toras HaBayis* ([ch. 10](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=33083&st=&pgnum=22)). The Chafetz Chaim notes the symbolism in how the angels on the ladder in Ya'akov's dream were either ascending or descending but could not remain static on the same level ([*B'reishis* 28:12](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0128.htm#12)).

The Chafetz Chaim generically cites "the holy *sefarim*" for this interpretation of the verse, but he expands on the concept at length.

Comment: The fact that he appeals to the "holy sefarim" implies that the source is **not** in Chazal.

Comment: @mevaqesh Probably true (though it's not a guarantee). This explanation of the *pasuk* most likely does not trace all the way back to Chazal, but I do often hear it associated with this idea. Anyway, I often see contemporary books cite "Chazal" for a concept that originated later, so maybe that's the case in the OP.

Comment: @mevaqesh possibly could be of the early kabbalistic sefarim, like the Zohar, which are written in large part by Tannaim...

Answer (score 3):

Here's my guess from Maseches Avos.

פרק א - משנה יג וּדְלָא מוֹסִיף, יָסֵיף 
The Bartenura explains

ודלא מוסיף. מי שאינו מוסיף על לימודו: יסיף. יסוף מפיו מה שכבר למד וישכח תלמודו.

Whoever doesn't add to his learning will forget what he already learnt.

Comment: What does remembering Torah have to do with the question?

Comment: It's a statement about the lack of a status quo.