# Source of idea of "no spiritual stasis"

Tags: sources-mekorot, mussar-ethics

What is the origin of the Mussar old adage that there is no such thing as spiritual stasis; one is always either ascending or descending spiritually?

Comment: How do you know this is a Mussar idea, that you ask about its origin? Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29352/759 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/61134/759

Comment: I think we can consider this a dup of that one.

Comment: @yitznewton I'm not so sure it's an exact dup, it depends if he wants to know who adapted it to the escalator metaphor specifically, which is a different question.

Comment: Hmm I see... I'll wait to see where the commentary goes before I do anything more.

Answer (score 0):

The source is probably the [commentary of the Gra](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14229&st=&pgnum=94&hilite=) (Rabbi Eliyahu of Vilna) to Mishlei 15:24.

Comment: Could you add a link, quote the passage, or summarize its contents?

Comment: Even given the link, you should copy the Gra and translate it.